# MySQL Word Boundary Queries with Hyphen

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using following  REGEXP to search

```
[[:<:]]word1[[:>:]]
```

But problem is hyphen in mysql regex is a word-boundary.  so  if search with  'security', it matches  'info-security', 'network-security'  also.

Is there way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace the hyphens in the string to match with underscores or the empty string.

REPLACE(columnname, '-', '_') REGEXP ...

Comment: That wont work. My aim is NOT matching those hypen separated words.  Your solution still matches those.

Comment: select 'word1-etc' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word1[[:>:]]' returns 1, select 'word1_etc' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word1[[:>:]]' returns 0

Comment: ah.. I see it now as underscore is not word-boundary. it works.  My bad.  But I need to replace hypens in input also.